# CSS minimized mode in Opera: positioning in speed dial extension

Tags: css, opera, minimized, opera-extension

I'm trying to display a scrolling list inside a speed dial box but have a problem with the positioning

I want to know when the list object is too big to fit the box, but as far as I know, there's no way of getting the size of the box in pixels

how can I get the minimized mode to show exactly what it's seen in the normal mode but fitting the box?

this is the CSS I'm using right now

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  color: #444;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
output {
position:absolute;
 width: 100%;
  white-space:nowrap;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

it works fine if I open the file in a tab, but in the speed dial it's displayed zoomed in

Opera's guide uses this query:

```
@media screen and (view-mode: minimized) { }
```

which controls the way it's displayed in the speed dial, I think. but I don't know what to put in there

**UPDATE**
well, I ended up creating an element and assigning a bottom value of 0

like this:

```
var bottom = document.createElement('div');
bottom.className= "ylimit";
document.body.appendChild(bottom);
```

and in CSS:

```
div.ylimit{
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
}
```

then whenever I want to check or compare the height, I use bottom.offsetHeight

Comment: show a sample of the css u have so far

Comment: Just to clarify: You want the list in the speed dial to be a certain width, e.g. if it's 20% of the main window it should take up 20% of the speed dial window, and it's not resizing for the speed-dial window? Is 'output' the scrolling list? Have you tried just specifying the width and font-size as 20% within Opera's view-mode thing?

Comment: @waitinforatrai it works ok with "%" values, but I can't get the height of the list in "%".
I could move the list something like "-i%" and increment i, but I woudn't know when to stop